# JavaFX: Location is not set error in cmd

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-8

My project is running perfectly in eclipse but when I run the jar of the project in cmd, I got the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.` It seems that my FXML is not loaded correctly. I know this question has been asked many times but none of them can solve my problem. I have tried to use

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/application/MainWIndowView.fxml"));
AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
```

but I still have the error.

[Here is the structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/augmT.png)

The method Run in eclipse:

```
public void showMainWIndow() throws IOException, SQLException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/application/MainWIndowView.fxml"));
    AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

    MainWindowController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setMain(this, primaryStage);
    controller.setKeyPress();
    controller.bindWidthAndHeight();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

What's the wrong of my code?

Comment: Change `Main.class.getResource("/application/MainWIndowView.fxml")` to `Main.class.getResource("MainWindowView.fxml")`

Comment: Using `/` will cause it to look up from the class path, which is different in JAR.

Comment: Thank you for your answers@devpuh but it doesn't work either. Actually I use the `FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("MainWIndowView.fxml"));`at first and then change it to what I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you@Jai but either use the `/` or not can't solve my problem

Comment: Check the content of your jar: run `jar tf MyJarFile.jar` from the command line. You want to check that the FXML file is included in the jar file, in the `application` package.

Comment: Also: note that the code you posted has a capital `I` in `MainWIndowView.fxml`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @James_D Ah...That's exactly my problem. It's very embarrassed. Thank you very much. Does it means that the eclipse is not case sensitive when it load the FXML?

Comment: When you run during development in Eclipse, it is loading the classes from the file system. So if you use an operating system that treats files the same, irrespective of the case of the file name, then it will find the right resource. Obviously, the same is not true in a jar file (or in any sensible operating system).

Comment: Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple change

```
Main.class.getResource("/application/MainWIndowView.fxml")
```

to

```
Main.class.getResource("MainWindowView.fxml")
```

And be careful with the case sensitivity, because you have a capital `I` in `MainWIndowView.fxml` but the file is named `MainWindowView.fxml`.

Thanks to [@James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189127) for pointing out:

> When you run during development in Eclipse, it is loading the classes
>   from the file system. So if you use an operating system that treats
>   files the same, irrespective of the case of the file name, then it
>   will find the right resource. Obviously, the same is not true in a jar
>   file (or in any sensible operating system).